# Store all the node pointers in an array of pointers for Binary Search Tree

Tags: pointers, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Recently I was trying to manipulate the binary search tree and got stuck here. I want to have an array(array of pointers) inside which I want to store the pointers of each node of the binary search tree in in-order fashion. I DON'T NEED THE VALUE OF EACH NODE I need the pointers so that I can access their value, left subtree and right subtree. What I have done is

```
struct node{
int key;
struct node *left, *right;
};

node **arr;
int x=0;

void inorder(struct node *root){
if (root != NULL){
    inorder(root->left);

    //cout<<"X : "<<x<<endl;
    arr[x] = root;
    x++;
    printf("%d \n", root->key);
    inorder(root->right);
}
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Looks right. What's going wrong?

Comment: The problem is when I use arr[i]->value then it brings up an error.

Comment: What Kind of Error? It probably should be arr[i]->Key though...

Comment: I am using Dev C++ and it shows an error like "[Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'node' "

Comment: The error message seems to suggest arr[i].key, but that seems inconsistent with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but if sorted array of node pointers satisfies your needs, then you don't need a binary search tree: you can perform binary search on the array. This data structure has the same access speed as a tree (can be even slightly faster because data is tightly packed in memory) and is very memory efficient. But insertion of new data is costly: o(n). So this solution is not appropriate if many insertions are expected. But in this case by maintaining that sorted array you loose all benefits of tree structure.